# mount.cifs version 6.4 error(5): Input/output error

Tags: mount, cifs

I want to mount a drive from my university, it worked before when I was using Linux mint Sarah.

Now I have

```
mount.cifs version 6.4, 
cifs-utils 2:6.4-1ubuntu1.1,
Linux mint version 18.3 (Sylvia), 
Kernel version 4.13.0-41-generic.
```

Here is what I write in `/etc/fstab`:

```
//<server>/<drive> /home/XXX/<drive> cifs credentials=/home/XXX/.credentials 0 0
```

This is how my .credentials looks like:

```
username=<myusername>
password=<mypassword>
```

In order to mount:

```
sudo mount --verbose <drive>
```

**The error message is:**

```
mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=<myIP>,unc=\\<server>\<drive>,user=<myusername>,pass=********
mount error(5): Input/output error
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

Here is what I tried: I tried `sec=ntlm`, but there will be an other error message. I checked if mount.cifs has set the suid-root Bit. I checked if I am in the same domain as the server. I checked my username and password and the server address, it's all correct.

Any other ideas what I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below configuration in fstab file

```
//<server>/<drive> /home/XXX/<drive> cifs credentials=/home/XXX/.credentials,sec=ntlm 0 0
```

Comment: As I wrote before, I tried sec=ntlm exactly as you write it. Here is the error message: `mount error(22): Invalid argument
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)`

Comment: in .credential file use proper format i.e. 

user=yourusername
password=yourpassword

Please try and let me know

Comment: Entering `username=` into `user=` solved the problem!